# [Solved]Ubuntu set network speed at 100

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet, download-speed

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu, and I have a gigabit internet connection. Previously, I was able to achieve speeds of around 400 Mbps (previous ISP claimed 1Gbps but underdelivered). However, after reinstalling Ubuntu, I noticed that the network settings now indicate a connection speed of 100 Mbps instead of 1000 Mbps. And i have no idea why. Can i fix it somehow?

```
Kernel version - 5.15.0-76-generic
Ubuntu - 20.04.6 LTS
```

[Solved] My rj45 socket wasn't wired properly, few cables were simply not connected and only 100Mbps was available, rewired it and got my 1Gbps

Comment: If your motherboard does not support Gigabit Ethernet, it means it only supports Fast Ethernet which is 100 Mbps. So it seems impossible you were achieving 400 Mbps download speed with 100 Mbps connection. If your system was really showing 1000 Mbps connection previously, that means your motherboard **does** support Gigabit Ethernet - otherwise it could not use 1000 Mbps speed. So it isn't clear what does your hardware actually support?

Comment: @raj, to be honest, I'm not entirely sure if my motherboard supports gigabit Ethernet. I assumed it did because I have a gigabit internet plan, but it's possible that my internet provider doesn't deliver the full speed. My motherboard is quite old, so I think I'll open up my PC and verify it. On previous ubuntu in network settings under "Wired" it said "Connected - 1000 Mb/s", i saw another post with similar problem and updating kernel help, but i'm not experienced enough

Comment: If it said connected at 1000 Mbit/s, then your board definitely supports Gigabit Ethernet. However, I don't know why it has switched to 100 Mbit/s now. Probable something regarding speed/duplex autonegotiation between your network card and the switch/modem/router. You may try to set negotiation to manual in connection properties, and try to manually force 1000 Mbit/s speed - maybe it helps.

Comment: @raj, any advice how to do it? Or what i should google to do it?

Comment: There should be options for it in your connection properties. Click on Network Manager's connection icon in your top bar, and there should be an option to "Modify connections" there. At least I do have it. Or try to run `nm-connection-editor` from the terminal.

Comment: @raj , tried ```nm-connection-editor```, set negotiations to manual and forced 1 Gb/s, still 100mb/s((

Comment: You can try to install `ethtool` utility and force the connection to 1000 Mbit/s using that. Maybe this works (however I don't know how to integrate this with Network Manager so that it's done automatically when connection is brought up). If this doesn't work, I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.